# GNS3 v2 router to host connection

Tags: arp, linux, gns3

I'm trying to make a router inside GNS3 to connect to the host device (a Debian 8) with no success. Am I missing something?

[image]

DHCP works as expected:

```
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address dhcp
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
```

IP is assigned to the router:

```
%DHCP-6-ADDRESS_ASSIGN: Interface FastEthernet0/0 assigned DHCP address 192.168.56.104, mask 255.255.255.0, hostname R1
```

When I ping from the host to the router I see (tcpdump) the ARP reply:

```
13:12:08.902370 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.56.104 tell 192.168.56.101, length 28
13:12:08.905452 ARP, Reply 192.168.56.104 is-at cc:01:43:49:00:00, length 46
```

But it is not populated in the host ARP table:

```
$ sudo arp -a
? (192.168.56.104) at <incomplete> on eth1
```

But it is on the router:

```
R1#sh arp
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  192.168.56.101          2   xxxx.xxxx.3f96  ARPA   FastEthernet0/0
Internet  192.168.56.104          -   cc01.4349.0000  ARPA   FastEthernet0/0
```

And when I ping from the router to the host, the host won't reply. A tcpdump capture on the host:

```
18:40:19.862855 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.56.101 tell 192.168.56.104, length 46
18:40:21.804763 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.56.101 tell 192.168.56.104, length 46
18:40:23.781876 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.56.101 tell 192.168.56.104, length 46
```

There is no rules in iptables:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Can you ping the other way (router to host)?

Comment: No, it won't ping from any side.

Comment: Have you tried with a manual ARP entry on the host? Not likely, but maybe ARP is a problem.

Comment: I did add a manual ARP, but it won't work either: `sudo arp -s 192.168.56.104 cc:01:43:49:00:00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed this for quite awhile with GNS3. I imagine that while you can see the ARP's via wireshark on the host, the host isn't actually *receiving* them. They're being sent out the host interface as if it was generating the traffic. Hence, it doesn't respond to its "own" ARP.

There is probably a 'better' or 'more correct' way to get around this problem, but I found that creating a TAP interface on the host and bridging it with the physical interface using the `ip` command will suffice.

I'm able to provide the GNS3 router a DHCP address from my LAN via connecting it to a GNS3 cloud using the TAP interface I created on the host. The GNS3 router can reach all devices including the host, as well as the internet. Connectivity remains 'normal' on the host.

I don't recall what specific configuration may be necessary for the GNS3 cloud, as it automatically populated the TAP interface and offered it as a connection for the router. (You will probably have to start GNS3 after performing the below, however.)

Here's the script I use:

```
# Adjust these as desired.
PHY_INT=enp9s0
TUN_INT=tap0
BR_INT=br0

case "$1" in
        up)
                echo "Creating bridge ..."
                # Create bridge interface
                ip link add $BR_INT type bridge
                # Create TAP interface
                ip tuntap add $TUN_INT  mode tap
                ip link set $TUN_INT  up
                # Flush IP from physical interface
                ip add flush dev $PHY_INT
                # Add interfaces to bridge
                ip link set $TUN_INT master $BR_INT
                ip link set $PHY_INT master $BR_INT
                ip link set dev $BR_INT up

                # DHCP
                dhclient -v $BR_INT

                ;;
        down)
                echo "Removing bridge ..."
                ip link del $TUN_INT
                ip link del $BR_INT
                dhclient -v $PHY_INT
                ;;
        *)
                echo $"Usage: $0 {up|down}"
                exit 1
esac
```

I'm on Debian Stretch (9) and GNS3 2.0.3.

Comment: Excellent! I connected the router interface to the cloud `br0` interface and voilà, it finally worked.